# Which version of linux OS has support for MongoDB installation?

Tags: mongodb, linux, installation, ubuntu

I would like to learn how to install MongoDB in my Windows machine. Currently I have a Windows 8 64 bit OS laptop and I installed MongoDB 64 version for Windows.

My question is: which version of linux (64 bit) supports my machine to install MongoDB.
I known Ubuntu linux only. Is it suitable for installing on my machine? Currently my machine has 64 bit version.

Thanks in advance for clarifying my doubt.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to easily install on most (if not all) flavours of x86-based Linux distributions.

There are officially packaged versions for:

- [Ubuntu](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/)
- [Debian](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-debian/)
- [RPM (Redhat, CentOS, Fedora, Amazon Linux)](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat-centos-or-fedora-linux/)

You can also [install from tarball](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-linux/), or check if there are packages available in the "ports" equivalent for your distribution.